# Disable woocommerce product reports

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woocommerce for another use that sell product and I want to disable woocommerce reports cause I suspect it slow down my website (In Query monitor, the query to update `wp_options` with `_transient_wc_report_sales_by_date` take too much time)

Can we disable it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Woocommerce reports will be created at runtime. Which means if you click in the administration on "Reports" woocommerce pulls the data from the database and shows them as fancy diagrams.

The option "_transient_wc_report_sales_by_date" works as a cache for the "Sales by date" database query. The cache will be created at the same time as Woocommerce retrieves the data form the database.

If you want to look at the code by yourself you find the "implemention" in the [class WC_Admin_Report method get_order_report_data](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Report.html#75).

In my opinion if you really do not need the reports, then the easiest way would be to remove the whole menue point from the administration. So the database query will not be triggert.